# coverage.py: Exclude function definitions without excluding function bodies

Tags: python, code-coverage, coverage.py

I've been trying to set coverage.py up to exclude all lines that are not in function bodies. Specifically, I'm only interested in what functions have been executed, and what parts of the function bodies that have been executed. I've tried solving this by adding regexes to the exclude list for everything I don't care about (imports,  docstrings), but as soon as I add:

```
cov.exclude('^def ')
```

not only are the function definition lines excluded, but the function bodies as well. Is it possible to get what I want?

Comment: Why are you trying to exclude the function definitions?  They've been executed, right, so why not measure them?

Comment: I guess it's somewhat unintended usage, but I'm trying to use coverage.py to exclusively measure how much of a web API has been called (where each Python function wraps an API call). Basically, I'm only interested in which functions have been executed by callers.

Comment: I wouldn't try to slice the results too finely: if you measure the entire Python file, it will tell you when you are missing particular function calls.  The actual percentage number doesn't matter so much.  If you want an "API percentage" instead of a "Python percentage", then estimate what percentage of the Python is executed just by importing the module, and discount that from your coverage total.

Comment: I have the same problem (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54811638/how-to-instruct-coverage-py-to-omit-top-level-definitions-and-count-only-method).  There I explain I can't control when the modules are loaded, so I only need to count the bodies and not the definitions.

Comment: Has anyone came up with a way to do this?