# How to instruct coverage.py to omit top-level definitions and count only method's bodies?

Tags: python, coverage.py

I want to test the coverage of a single package within a large body of software (specifically an Odoo addon).  I have no control over the overall setup of the test.  Hacking Odoo to start the coverage collection before loading the modules is not worth it -- running all Odoo tests takes about 20 minutes on regular hardware; so I want to selectively test the coverage of some custom modules.

I'm using `setUpModule` and `tearDownModule` like this:

```
_coverage = Coverage(
    source=[
        'odoo.addons.xhg_autrement_prices.models',
    ],
    config_file=_join('.coveragerc'),
    auto_data=True,
    data_file=_join('.coverage'),
)


def setUpModule():
    _coverage.start()


def tearDownModule():
    from test.support import captured_stderr
    _coverage.stop()
    _coverage.save()
    with captured_stderr() as stderr:
        total = _coverage.report(skip_covered=True, file=sys.stderr)
    report = stderr.getvalue()
    fail_under = _coverage.get_option('report:fail_under')
    assert not fail_under or total >= fail_under, \
        f"Coverage not reached. total: {total}; expected: {fail_under}\n{report}"
```

However, when the test machinery calls the `setUpModule` the models module under test have already been loaded by Odoo.

So, coverage.py reports the lines defining some functions (or classes) as misses.  For instance, in the following class:

```
class SumAggregator(SimpleAggregator):
    '''Aggregate by sum.'''
    def __init__(self, start: Result = 0) -> None:
        self.start = start

    def __call__(self, results: Iterable[Result], env: Environment) -> Result:
        return sum(results, self.start)
```

The line that defines the `__call__` method is reported not covered, but its body is a hit.  The first 3 lines (the class definition, its docstring and the **init** definition) are reported missed.  Noticeable **all docstrings** (which comprise about about 10% of the source code) are reported missed.

How can instruct coverage to omit top-level definitions and count only the bodies of classes or functions (methods)?

Comment: I've been wondering the same a couple days ago, and it seems that the only way is to add def, async def, class, etc. to ignored patterns.

Comment: @Norrius That doesn't work because then their bodies get ignored as well.